# How to operate each array entry with a different number to solve an optimization condition in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have an array A of the form:

```
1.005    1.405   1.501   1.635
2.020    2.100   2.804   2.067
3.045    3.080   3.209   3.627
4.080    4.005   4.816   4.002
5.125    5.020   5.025   5.307
6.180    6.045   6.036   6.015
7.245    7.320   7.049   7.807
8.320    8.125   8.064   8.042 
9.405    9.180   9.581   9.060 
10.500   10.245  10.100  10.082
```

and B of the form:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

I would like to add or subtract each of the entries with a number that is less than a particular number, in this case 0.5, so that certain conditions are met, e.g. sum of (Bi-Ai)^2 is minimized, much like an optimization problem. As an example, let us take A23, that has a value 2.804, I need to vary it between 2.304 < A23 < 2.804 so that for a particular value in this range, the sum of  of (Bi-Ai)^2. And then for A24 I vary it between 1.567 < A24 < 2.567 so that, D is minimized.

**Reproducible code**

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1.005, 1.405, 1.501, 1.635], 
        [2.020, 2.100, 2.804, 2.067], 
        [3.045, 3.080, 3.209, 3.627], 
        [4.080, 4.005, 4.816, 4.002],
        [5.125, 5.020, 5.025, 5.307], 
        [6.180, 6.045, 6.036, 6.015], 
        [7.245, 7.320, 7.049, 7.807], 
        [8.320, 8.125, 8.064, 8.042], 
        [9.405, 9.180, 9.581, 9.060], 
        [10.500, 10.245, 10.100, 10.082]])
B = np.array([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
C = np.empty(shape = (A.shape[0], A.shape[1]))
D = np.empty(shape = (A.shape[0], ))
m, n = A.shape
for i in range(m):
    for j in range (n):
        C[i, j] = np.sum((B[i] - A[i, j]) ** 2)
D = np.sum(C, axis = 0)
```

Comment: Have you considered formally setting this up as a minimzation problem and using [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)? This seems like it fits the bill for [constrained minimization](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#constrained-minimization-of-multivariate-scalar-functions-minimize).

Comment: I am more concerned about the operation on entries in A that can achieve the minimum value.